# Какой смысл имеет дополнительная постановка запятых при обособлении вставки двумя тире?

Tags: запятые, правила, вставная-конструкция

**NEW!** Правила разные, но возможны **три варианта:**

1. **Смещение запятой налево:**

*Он посмотрел на пепелище, которое окружало его, — **какой ужас!** — и руки бессильно опустились у него.*

2. **Смещение запятой направо:**

*Когда он начинает сомневаться в себе — **а это с ним изредка происходит**, — он пытается стать рационалистом.*

3. **Нет смещения, симметричный знак:**

*Проводя почти всё своё время неразлучно с матерью, потому что я и писал и читал в её отдельной горнице, где обыкновенно и спал, — **там стояла моя кроватка и там был мой дом**, — я менее играл с сестрицей, реже виделся с ней.*

**ВОПРОС:** Такая постановка знаков **имеет смысл** или это **простая формальность**? На сколько **частей** мы делим предложение по смыслу в каждом варианте (**два или три** блока).

**Примечание**

Зачем это знать? Хотелось бы ориентироваться в теме не только формально, но и по **семантике** тоже. Такой выбор можно сделать достаточно **быстро**, а потом при необходимости **проверить** по правилам.

Answer (score 0):

Правильно так — и только! Не надо придумывать правила.

> Когда он начинает сомневаться в себе, — а это с ним изредка происходит — он пытается стать рационалистом.

> Проводя почти всё своё время неразлучно с матерью, потому что я и писал и читал в её отдельной горнице, где обыкновенно и спал, — там стояла моя кроватка и там был мой дом.

Я вообще не люблю никак перенос знаков так, чтоб запятая одна была в конце вставки, а не в начале. Это возможно, только если вторая часть этого требует. Но не первая! Просто это ещё сложнее тогда всё становится, а и так уж супернелегко.

Comment: Спасибо за ваше мнение. Но кто же придумывает правила? У кого такие полномочия?  Я — никогда!  Я могу предложить новую методику решения, могу ее применять и применяю,  но правила для меня — это святое! А как иначе?  Решать можно по-своему, а вот само решение нужно оформить по правилам,  да еще ссылочку приложить: на правила, на грамматику. А как делаете вы, сэр?  О, совсем не так.  Ответы принимаете, а ссылки не спрашиваете. Я  пишу: грамматика неверная! А вы и внимания не обращаете, да и не читаете вовсе. Я пишу: правило сложно подобрать,  но ответ принимается и без правил.

Comment: А сейчас? Все мои примеры из Розенталя, что же тут придуманного? Ровным счетом ничего, а вот вы их переделываете! Посмотрите на ответ Максима:  https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/476572/У-Вас-фамилия-Медведева-не-Медведьева-так Мне думается,  он меня слушает внимательно: смотрит, к какой части относится вставка, правильно смещает запятую. Это само решение (по смыслу), а отчитаться можно по Розенталю.  Трудны ли такие задачи? Непонимание смысла решения делает их трудными. А если задача нестандартная? Тогда и Розенталь не поможет. Это всё, что я имею сказать вам, сэр.

Answer (score 0):

Не автор решил так знаки поставить  — структура решила. Всë объясняется правилами. И везде знаки расставлены верно:

*Он посмотрел на пепелище, которое окружало его, — какой ужас! — и руки бессильно опустились у него* — вставка относится к существительному *пеплище*, но придаточное разрывает вставку и дополнение, поэтому придаточное нужно обособить с двух сторон, т. к. вставка к нему не относится;

*Когда он начинает сомневаться в себе — а это с ним изредка происходит, — он пытается стать рационалистом* — вставка относится к придаточному, поэтому запятой их друг от друга не отделяем и закрываем с правой стороны. Я не согласен с Лео по поводу запятой слева;

*Проводя почти всё своё время неразлучно с матерью, потому что я и писал и читал в её отдельной горнице, где обыкновенно и спал, — там стояла моя кроватка и там был мой дом, — я менее играл с сестрицей, реже виделся с ней* — вставка относится к обстоятельству *в горнице*, но их разрывает придаточное, к которому вставка не относится, поэтому обособляем его с двух сторон. Запятая перед вторым тире закрывает деепричастный оборот, в состав которого входит вставка (обстоятельство *в горнице* относится туда же, а вставка — это его «зависимое слово», поэтому вставка в его составе), поэтому отделяем вставку и от последующей части, относя еë к обороту.

---

Следует отметить, что если бы не было восклицательного знака, запятая бы ставилась и на его месте (перед обоими тире):

*Он посмотрел на пепелище, которое окружало его, — какой ужас, — и руки бессильно опустились у него*.

Перед первым тире стоит запятая я уже объяснял почему, а запятая перед вторым тире ставится между частями ССП. Вставка если не относится к следующей части, то отделяется от неë запятой.

Если же вставка относится к следующей части, то запятая только перед первым тире:

*Он посмотрел на пепелище, которое окружало его, — какой ужас — и руки бессильно опустились у него*.

Вставка относится к следующей части — не отделяем их друг от друга. Запятая перед первым тире стоит на двух основаниях.

Comment: Спасибо, Максим, за внимание к вопросу. К сожалению, не могу с вами согласиться по поводу отнесенности вставки, я понимаю все по-другому. Позже  дам оба ответа по вставкам, а пока времени нет. Согласна с восклицательным знаком, он действительно заменяет запятую (по аналогии с прямой речью).

Comment: @Sharon С чем именно вы не согласны?

Comment: @Sharon И всë-таки, с чем вы не согласны?